# Using modernblink plugin for blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the modern blink plugin (https://github.com/leonderijke/jQuery-Modern-Blink) for my website to blink my div. I'm using below to call the function to blink. Iteration count means the number of blink:

```
$('#mydiv').modernBlink({iterationCount: 5});
```

My application requires the div to blink upon pressing a button. But I found out that I can't run the modernBlink function to blink #mydiv more than once. It only blink the first time I press the button. After that there's no respond when I press the button.
But I saw from console there's this error:

> Uncaught  jquery.modern-blink.js:162 TypeError: (options || "").replace is not a function.

Any ideas why?